# What do tab colors mean in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've recently started using PyCharm and it's autosave system is very confusing to me. Colorful tabs are even more confusing: what do the different tab color mean? There're tabs with blue text, black and red. What's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the [File Status Highlights](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/file-status-highlights.html). Tab background color can be also different depending on the [Scope](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/file-colors.html).

Comment: Thanks! But i don't quite get it. What is "synchronization"? Or do they mean sync with repository?

Comment: It's the Version Control state.

Comment: Beware that File Status setting changed in PyCharm 2017.1 version and is set in very awkward way for custom schemes: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000129050-File-status-colours-for-custom-scheme